# richfaces how to detect mouse position

Tags: jsf, mouse, richfaces, position

How can I detect the mouse position on a "onclick" event in RichFaces?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `<rich:jQuery>` component.

```
<rich:jQuery selector="#myButtonId" query="click(function(event) {alert("Mouse Position: " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY );})" />
```

Regards.